# How to derive viewbox height and width to web page height and width

Tags: javascript, svg

**Svg defination**

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
           xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
          xmlns:xxx="http://www.abcdef.com/xxx"    
         id="svgId"
     version="1.1" 
     xml:space="preserve" 
     viewBox="0 0 1191 739">....</svg>
```

Problem is here that

i want to place(map) this svg in my webpage in a domElement-div

```
<div style='width:500px ;height:700px'></div>
```

I'm facing problem in map svg to webpage layout

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: What precisely is the problem? What does it look like now and what do you want it to look like?

Comment: Problem is Mapping between SVG viewbox co-cordintes to Web layout. viewbox(Vx , Vy , Vwidth,Vheight) and the div has Dwidth and Dheight, How to map Vwidth to Dwidth and Vheight to Dheight,Here i want to maintain svg aspect ratio (it should not be streached badly or shrined )

Comment: If you want to preserve the aspect ratio, add a preserveAspectRatio="whatever is appropriate to you" attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from this PDF

*http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~parent/classes/581/Lectures/4.2DviewingHandout.pdf*
(page number 5 , 6, 7)

'Hint ' :

Match aspect ratios of both windows

```
R > W / H

Viewport(0, 0, W, W/R)
```

---

```
R < W / H

Viewport(0, 0, H*R, H)
```

Were r = w/h of viewport of Webpage